# react-admin add font with override MuiCssBaseline @global @font-face not working

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, font-face, react-admin

I am trying to add the `NotoSansSC-Regular.otf` from Google to `react-admin` so that the default font for simplified Chinese will be that. I have successfully got it working if I do a CSS include of the fonts in the root html file, via a:

```
  typography: {
    fontFamily: ["Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif", "notasansregular"].join(","),
  },
```

In my themes. All the examples I found suggest I can also get this working via:

```
import notasansregular from "../../public/fonts/chinese/NotoSansSC-Regular.otf";
...
const notafont = {
  fontFamily: "notasansregular",
  fontStyle: "normal",
  fontWeight: "normal",
  src: `
    url(${notasansregular}) format('opentype')
  `,
};
...
const myTheme = {
...
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      "@global": {
        "@font-face": [notafont],
      },
    },
...
}
```

But absolutely nothing I tried got it working, including using the same URL (just the bare filename in the `url('NotoSansSC-Regular.otf')`), which is exactly what is working when I include via CSS in the index.html.

A few of the examples I saw put the `<CssBaseline />` directly inside a `ThemeProvider` in the JSX but `react-admin` has in a place it is very inconvenient to try and override, given I have no idea whether this is the issue and placing it in other possible places (outside or inside `<Admin />`) make no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Mui v5, [the syntax is slightly different](https://mui.com/customization/typography/#font-family):

```js
const myTheme = createTheme({
  components: { // not overrides!
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: `
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Noto Sans SC';
          font-style: normal;
          font-display: swap;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: local('NotoSansSC'), 
               local('NotoSansSC-Regular.otf'), 
               url(${notasansregular}) format('otf');
          unicodeRange: // the unicode range for SC
        }
      `,
    },
  },
})
```

**ETA:** [Mui 4 demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-add-font-with-override-muicssbaseline-global-font-face-not-working-93b77)

Comment: Thanks but I'm still on v4 while react-admin hasn't updated.

Comment: @AntonOfTheWoods I have added a MUI 4 version.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for Mui v5 and multiple fonts:

```
import AbradeRegular from 'assets/fonts/Abrade-Regular.ttf'
import AbradeMedium from 'assets/fonts/Abrade-Medium.ttf'
....

const abradeRegular = {
  fontFamily: 'Abrade',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: 'normal',
  src: `url(${AbradeRegular}) format('truetype')`,
}

const abradeMedium = {
  fontFamily: 'Abrade',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: 500,
  src: `url(${AbradeMedium}) format('truetype')`,
}
....

theme.components = {
  MuiCssBaseline: {
    styleOverrides: {
      html: [
        {'@font-face': abradeLight},
        {'@font-face': abradeRegular},
        {'@font-face': abradeMedium},
        {'@font-face':abradeSemiBold},
        {'@font-face': abradeBold},
        {'@font-face':abradeExtraBold},
        {'@font-face':abradeBlack}
      ],
      'html, body': {
        padding: 0,
        scrollbarWidth: 'thin',
      },
}}}
```

Comment: +1, This was the solution I needed because in addition to having custom fonts defined, I also needed a way to add specific styles to `body`. Also worth pointing out that styleOverrides accepts a function which returns the overrides as well and in that func, you can access the `theme` object

Answer (score 0):

Mui documentation's string CSS template syntax :

Warning : don't add comma `,` between @font-face declarations.

```
import PoppinsRegular from '@assets/fonts/poppins-regular.woff2';
import PoppinsBold from '@assets/fonts/poppins-bold.woff2';
import PoppinsSemiBold from '@assets/fonts/poppins-semibold.woff2';

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
        'Poppins',
        'sans-serif',
        ].join(','),
  },
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: `
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Poppins';
          font-style: normal;
          font-display: swap;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: url(${PoppinsRegular}) format('woff2');
        }
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Poppins';
          font-style: normal;
          font-display: swap;
          font-weight: 700;
          src: url(${PoppinsBold}) format('woff2');
        }
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Poppins';
          font-style: normal;
          font-display: swap;
          font-weight: 600;
          src: url(${PoppinsSemiBold}) format('woff2');
        },
      `,
    },
  },
});
```